# append a button with an action and attributes

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am making a table where it get some data from MySQL and display them. The user add information and data are added and appended using Ajax.

The problem is that each line of the table contain a delete button. And when appending a new line, I finally was able to append a button with it.

But this button don't do any actions until I refresh the page. If we take facebook. When a new status or photos are added, their is multiple button with actions that are appended with. So how to append a button with its action.

So in my table every delete button should take the row id to delete it.
Here is some scripts:

To append a button with the new line:

```
var btn = '<button type="Button" id="delete">Delete</button>';

$("#before_tr").before("<tr><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+address+"</td><td>"+phone+"</td><td>"+btn+"</td></tr>");
```

Comment: What action needs to be performed?

Comment: If the user want to delete the newely added row for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As you are creating elements dynamically.**

You need to use  [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

*General Syntax*

```
$(staticParentElement).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

Add a class, since *identifiers in HTML must be unique*

```
var btn = '<button type="Button" class="delete">Delete</button>';
```

*Example*

```
$(document).on('click', ".delete", function(){
    //code to remove row
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Note: In place of `document` you should use closest static container.

Comment: so I will be able to delete the final row added from the page and from database ?

Comment: @androidnation from database you need to make call to api to delete the data

Comment: Can you tell me how ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript.

```
var btn = '<button onClick="return confirm('Delete $id ?') type="Button" id="delete">Delete</button>';
```